# command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, error-handling

I'm getting the `command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11?` error but its pretty ambiguous to me as of why? it does provide the following response in the debugger however pointing to the following code:

```
1.  While type-checking 'textFieldShouldEndEditing' at /Users/macbookair1/Documents/programming/MyApp/MyApp/SignUpViewController.swift:224:5
2.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/macbookair1/Documents/programming/MyApp/MyApp/SignUpViewController.swift:231:9 - line:252:11] RangeText="query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
            if error == nil {
                if (objects!.count > 0){


                    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).signUpOn {
                    let myAlert = SCLAlertView().showError("Woah There", subTitle: "username \(textField.text!) is already taken", closeButtonTitle: "Got It")
                    myAlert.alertview.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
                    myAlert.alertview.circleBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
                    myAlert.alertview.labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                    myAlert.alertview.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0).CGColor
                    myAlert.alertview.viewText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                    myAlert.alertview.viewText.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Username is available.")
                }
            } else {
                print("error")
            }
          }"
```

and another pointing to this code:

```
1.  While type-checking 'loadBooks' at /Users/macbookair1/Documents/programming/MyApp/MyApp/ThirdCollectionViewController.swift:103:5
2.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/macbookair1/Documents/programming/MyApp/MyApp/ThirdCollectionViewController.swift:108:9 - line:127:9] RangeText="query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.books.removeAll()
                let bookObjects = objects as! [PFObject]
                for (_, object) in bookObjects.enumerate() {
                    self.books.append(Book(pfBook: object))
                }
            }else if let secondMessage = error?.userInfo["error"] as? String
                where secondMessage == "The Internet connection appears to be offline." {
                    self.failedMessage(secondMessage)
                    self.activityIndicator.hidden = true
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                self.collectionView!.reloadData()
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
        }"
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of error that can occur in LLVM itself while compiling swift.
Try using an alternative expression or using a newer version of swift (such as 2.0 as of writing), I have encountered this and certain times expressions will just cause a crash, and splitting assignments up or even using objective-c will not cause a crash.

Comment: i believe it has to do with my `"query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` statement of both code blocks

Comment: It can error on perfectly valid lines of code. Try simplifying and breaking up into multiple parts. For instance once it would crash trying to create a URL of two components and I had to create one string and then another, and it worked.

Comment: so looking at the first code in the error, how should I break it up properly?

Comment: It's difficult to say because it's crash on the block as a whole, try moving the block to its own definition as a variable to separate it